# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address :

Tags: java, asmx, apache-axis, wsdl2java

Approach 1 stacktrace

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://username:password@10.XXX.15.XX/ClientExt/NewAPI/api.asmx?wsdl. It failed with: 
>       Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@10.XXX.15.XX/ClientExt/NewAPI/api.asmx?wsdl.
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:250)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)
>       at org.tempuri.Api.(Api.java:82)

approach 1:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

approach 2

```
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
String userCredentials = "username:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
myURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500000);
myURLConnection.connect();
int responseCode = myURLConnection.getResponseCode();//returns 200 and error
```

I am getting response Code 200 in approach 2, also getting above stacktrace as error message.

Then, I tried with Authenticator(approach 1), it is working fine if I call in javaTester file but getting below error message when calling through application.

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address : http://10.XXX.15.XX/ClientExt/NewAPI/api.asmx